# Installing gtk2hs on windows XP

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk2hs

I followed the instructions on http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs#Install_libxml to install gtk2hs on windows XP, after installing libxml and gtk/glade,
'cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools' succeeded.
but when run 'cabal install gtk' it gets: '*Missing C libraries:kernel32, gthread-2.0, gtk-win32-2.0, ....'
I think I have set all the environment variables, why can't it find the libs?

Comment: I just changed the gtk installation directory from the default C:\Program Files\GTK+ to C:\GTK and it's OK then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path with space is problematic, avoid those path and it will install.